# How can i clean the data in a column in r studio?

Tags: r, string, split, dataset

[image]

I want to clean the second column so there is only the name of the player. How can this be done?

Example:
André OnanaA. OnanaKeeper would be André Onana

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(Spelers, "\\."), '[', 1)`

Comment: Please post data a text, not pictures. We can't debug or demonstrate code with a picture of data as input. `dput()` is the nicest way to share data because it is copy/pasteable and preserves class and structure information, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows of your data.

Comment: How did the data get like this in the first place? It's will probably be easier to fix the data generatation step than try to clean up the mess afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `gsub` like below

```
df$Spelers <- gsub("\\..*","",df$Spelers)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Spelers = str_remove(Spelers, "\\..*"))
```

---

Or another option with `trimws`

```
df$Spelers <- trimws(df$Spelers, whitespace = "\\..*")
```